# View stack traces in Cursive REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen, cursive

I am developing a Clojure program from a REPL in Cursive. I would like to see stack traces with the error messages. By default it seems that only the error message is output.

If I 'Edit Configurations...' I can see that the REPL is a 'Clojure REPL' and that 'Use clojure.main in normal JVM process' is specified. I believe this is a fairly standard REPL setup with Cursive.

All the clojure source files are in the `user` namespace, and there is nothing special about the `project.clj` lein project file.

Currently if I want to see a stack trace I need to run the program like this:

```
(use 'clojure.stacktrace)
(x)
(print-stack-trace *e 30)
```

Here `(x)` is running the program that is crashing. These steps work from both the command line (starting off with `lein repl`) and from within the Cursive REPL.

Are there some setup steps that I can do so that stack traces are always shown with error messages and so `(use 'clojure.stacktrace)` and `(print-stack-trace *e 30)` become superfluous?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a keymap to "Print last exception" menu item.
Open the settings with `⌘,` then access `Keymap > Main Menu > Tools > REPL`.
Double click "Print last exception" and choose a shortcut. 
[image: my settings]

Comment: I don't have a `⌘` key on my keyboard.

Comment: In Windows it's `Ctrl+Alt+S`, otherwise take a look at [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-settings.html?keymap=primary_default)

Comment: Also `Ctrl+Alt+S` for Linux, so the same key for all non-Appleverse keyboards. I already had `(print-stack-trace *e 25)` as a Tools / REPL / Add new REPL command, but switched to your method, and found the keystroke now did nothing. So I had to switch back.